# Cors Error: Deploying Ionic App and Express Server on Linux VPS

Tags: node.js, express, ionic-framework

I'm having cors issues deploying my ionic app and my server on node, express on a linux VPS server. My configuration in my index.ts is as follows:

`server.app.use(cors({ origin:['IP_server:80','http://IP_server/login', 'http://IP_server', 'IP_server/*', 'localhost:80', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1'], credentials:true }));`

I have deployed the ionic application in nginx and when I write the IP address of the server it correctly opens the application redirecting to http://IP_server/login but when I try to log in it tells me the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/usuario/login' from origin 'http://IP_server' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
```

I don't know what else I can do, I have tried many settings and none of them have helped me. Can you help me please? Thanks

My /etc/nginx/sites-available/default is:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * always;

        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
         return 200;
        }

.........


 root /home/ubuntu/ionicproyecto/www;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;

        }
.........
```